Mouse wheel sometimes skips to the beginnin/end of the page
On Ubuntu 24.10 sometimes it happens that moving a bit the wheel mouse leads to go to the very beginning or end of the current page.
This happens in any applications: browsers, text editors, IDE, etc...
Is it a known bug or is it happening just to me?
I tried to search for similar issues but I found nothing relevant.
The same mouse on Ubuntu 24.04 has no problems.
